# Н > И change in Cyrillic, when and why?

Tags: история-языка, алфавит, буквы

The modern Cyrillic letter had the shape of H a thousand years ago, it descends from the Greek H η 'Ήτα, Ēta'. What is interesting is *when and why* this letter changed the angle of its bar from H to И.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Думаю что целенаправленного изменения штриха не было. Если посмотреть на заглавные буквы печатных книг, видно что штрих в букве И сначала был ровным, потом слегка наклоненным (как бы для удобства письма), затем этот наклон стал более выраженным.

[image: Начертания И][image: скорописная и]

Что касается буквы Н, которая писалась как N, то ее вариации тоже в своих крайних формах меняли наклон среднего штриха практически до такого, что отдельно взятая буква становится похожа на И.

[image: Скорописные н]

Думаю тут сыграло большую роль то что книги, в которых эти буквы претерпевали изменения были рукописными (и переписывались по многу раз), поэтому отдельные отклонения в начертании букв могли усиливаться переписчиками (точно так же как это происходит с устной речью).

Уже в полууставе буквы И и N имеют зеркальную форму, но сами штрихи, хоть и наклонные достаточно близки к горизонтали.

Как мне кажется, решающим моментом в истории наклонных штрихов букв И и Н был гражданский шрифт Петра I. В [первом варианте](http://www.paratype.ru/e-zine/issue04/peter1/peter1b.htm#5) (январь 1707) буква И присутствовала только в виде десятеричного I, а буква Н была уже утверждена с горизонтальным штрихом вместо наклонного. Этим шрифтом было напечатано несколько книг:

[image: шрифт 1707]

Но на этом Петр I не остановился - в 1710 году он утверждает [новую версию](http://www.paratype.ru/e-zine/issue04/peter1/peter1c.htm) гражданского шрифта в котором были изменены начертания нескольких букв и добавлены ранее пропущенные, в том числе и буква И:

[image: дополнительные буквы]

Вот тут, как мне кажется и произошел решающий поворот в этой истории. С появлением гражданского (не церковного) книгопечатанья и появления утвержденного шрифта начертания букв И и Н закрепляются. А форму с прямым штрихом буква Н получила в тот момент когда буква И "выпала" из проекта гражданского шрифта в 1708 году. Когда же добавили букву И, начертание Н уже было утверждено и из всех возможных вариантов оставался только с наклонным штрихом.

Comment: Как это относится к другим славянским языкам? Македонцы, сербы, болгары копировали с русского алфавита?

Comment: @Anixx - Да, все они копировали с русского алфавита, с петровского гражданского шрифта. Только румыны копировали с украинского языка, вернее с украинского церковнославянского шрифта, но ближе к середине XIX века, перед тем как они перешли на латиницу, они тоже стали часто использовать петровский гражданский шрифт.